# Is there a way to set the cgroup that systemd launches a process in?

Tags: systemd, cgroup

systemd launches a process in the /system.slice/process-name.service cgroup. I would like to launch the process in a different cgroup. I can do this using cgexec in the ExecStart option, but is there a better way?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Creat a `group-name.slice`, and set the resource control configuration in the slice unit, such as, `CPUShares=`, `MemoryLimit=`.

Then set `Slice=group-name.slice` in the `process-name.service`.

See `man systemd.resource-control` for details.

Comment: At this point, in ubuntu 20.04, no need to create `group-name.slice` before set it in `process-name.service`, seems `systemd` can create by it self